# SQL CASE and JOINS: How to get different counts and totals?

Tags: sql, count, sum, case

I am in need of some assistance. I would like to get a count of my activated, deactivated, and the total of users in my system for these columns.  The current output includes the names within the NAME column twice output as shown below that includes NULLS. I would like to eliminate the NULLs and also get a sub total of each column. Hope I can get some help with this.

```
  Current output:
- NAME   Activated  Deactivated 
- MAX     25          NULL
- MAX     NULL         5
- TAX     40          NULL
- TAX     NULL         10

    Desired output:
  - NAME   Activated  Deactivated 
   - MAX     25          5  
  - TAX     40          10
   -Total    65          15
```

Thanks.

```
select 
    case 
        when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER'
        end Name, count(*) 'Activated', null 'Deactivated'
from 
    membership.user_details d
    inner join membership.aspnet_membership m 
        on m.userid = d.userid
    inner join membership.user_notes n 
        on n.userid = d.userid
        and n.created_on = (
            select 
                min(created_on) 
            from 
                membership.user_notes 
            where 
                userid = n.userid
                and note = 'received.'
        )
        and substring(convert(varchar(8),n.created_on,112),1,6) = '201209'
where 
    approved = 1
group by       
    case 
        when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER'
        end      

union 

select 
    case 
        when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER'
        end Name,  
    null 'Activated', 
    count(*) 'Deactivated'
from 
    membership.user_details d
    inner join membership.aspnet_membership m 
        on m.userid = d.userid
    inner join membership.user_notes n 
        on n.userid = d.userid
        and n.CREATED_ON = (
            select 
                min(created_on) 
            from 
                membership.user_notes 
            where 
                userid = n.userid
                and note = 'SAAR received.'
        )
        and substring(convert(varchar(8),m.LastLockoutDate,112),1,6) = '201209'
where 
    approved = 1
group by       
    case 
        when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER'
        end
```

Comment: What are the table structures?

Comment: There are various tables that this sql script is getting the information from. 3 tables to be exact. On table is used to get the the email for the case and the next is used to see if the use was ever approved and another for when the user first entered the system(authorized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to consolidate this into a single `SELECT`:

```
select 
    case 
        when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER'
    end Name, 
    SUM(case when substring(convert(varchar(8),n.created_on,112),1,6) = '201209' then 1 else 0 end) 'Activated',
    SUM(case when substring(convert(varchar(8),m.LastLockoutDate,112),1,6) = '201209' then 1 else 0 end) 'Deactivated'
from membership.user_details d
inner join membership.aspnet_membership m 
    on m.userid = d.userid
inner join membership.user_notes n 
    on n.userid = d.userid
    and n.CREATED_ON = (select min(created_on) 
                        from membership.user_notes 
                        where userid = n.userid
                            and note = 'SAAR received.')  
where approved = 1
group by case when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
          when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
          else 'OTHER' end
```

This new version uses an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the total `Activated` and `Deactivated`. The `CASE` 
checks the dates that you were using each each query.

Then if you want to include a total row, you can use `GROUP BY with ROLLUP`

Comment: That did the trick. Im going to do some homework on the Group BY with ROLLUP beause I would like to add a total rom as well. I never used that function before. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @user1880670 Happy to help! :)  If you have any issues with `group by with rollup`, then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Change `null 'Deactivated'` and `null 'Activated'` to `0'Deactivated'` and `0'Activated'` respectively, then do a `GROUP BY Name WITH ROLLUP`